# change position of NA category on ggplot x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to change the position of `NA` on the x-axis of a `ggplot`? Below I set the `NA` level at the second position of the factor levels, but `NA` still appears at the last position on the x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- iris[c(1,2,51,52,101,102),]
dat[1,"Species"] <- NA
dat[["Species"]] <- factor(dat[["Species"]], 
                           levels = c("virginica", NA, "setosa", "versicolor"), 
                           exclude = NULL)
dat[["Species"]]
# [1] <NA>       setosa     versicolor versicolor virginica  virginica 
# Levels: virginica <NA> setosa versicolor
# NA is the second level

ggplot(dat, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
# NA appears at right
```

[image]

Comment: Change `NA` to `"No Data"` then plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use wanted order pass levels to `scale_x_discrete` `limits` argument:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(dat$Species))
```

From `scale_{x/y}_discrete` documentation:

> limits: A character vector that defines possible values of the
>                 scale and their order.

[image]